# Can't resolve service names on namespace kube-system

Tags: kubernetes

I've deployed my cluster on debian based on https://github.com/CiscoCloud/kubernetes-ansible.
Everything work fine except some addons and i suspect name resolution.

I've a rc defined like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  name: monitoring-influx-grafana-v1
  namespace: kube-system
  labels: 
    k8s-app: influxGrafana
    version: v1
    kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    k8s-app: influxGrafana
    version: v1
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        k8s-app: influxGrafana
        version: v1
        kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - image: gcr.io/google_containers/heapster_influxdb:v0.3
          name: influxdb
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
          ports: 
            - containerPort: 8083
              hostPort: 8083
            - containerPort: 8086
              hostPort: 8086
          volumeMounts:
          - name: influxdb-persistent-storage
            mountPath: /data
        - image: gcr.io/google_containers/heapster_grafana:v0.7
          name: grafana
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 100Mi
          env: 
            - name: INFLUXDB_EXTERNAL_URL
              value: /api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-influxdb:api/db/
            - name: INFLUXDB_HOST
              value: monitoring-influxdb
            - name: INFLUXDB_PORT
              value: "8086"
      volumes:
      - name: influxdb-persistent-storage
        emptyDir: {}
```

So the container connects to a host named "monitoring-influxdb".
Actually this name is well resolved by the dns when i use a "busy-box" pod:

```
kubectl exec busybox --namespace=kube-system -- nslookup monitoring-influxdb
Server:    10.233.0.10
Address 1: 10.233.0.10
```

Name:      monitoring-influxdb
Address 1: 10.233.83.114

But inside the monitoring-influx-grafana-v1 pod, the name is not resolved :

```
kubectl exec monitoring-influx-grafana-v1-obu8h --namespace=kube-system -- ping -c 1 monitoring-influxdb
PING monitoring-influxdb.kube-system.svc.osm.local (10.233.83.114) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- monitoring-influxdb.kube-system.svc.osm.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Note the "kubernetes" service is resolved

````
kubectl exec monitoring-influx-grafana-v1-obu8h --namespace=kube-system -- ping -c 1 kubernetes
PING kubernetes.default.svc.osm.local (10.233.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.233.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.441 ms

--- kubernetes.default.svc.osm.local ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
```
````

The service is defined as follows in etcd

```
{'apiVersion': 'v1',
 'kind': 'Endpoints',
 'metadata': {'creationTimestamp': '2015-08-31T16:11:47Z',
              'labels': {'kubernetes.io/cluster-service': 'true',
                         'kubernetes.io/name': 'InfluxDB'},
              'name': 'monitoring-influxdb',
              'namespace': 'kube-system',
              'resourceVersion': '219',
              'selfLink': '/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/endpoints/monitoring-influxdb',
              'uid': 'fab1bd0d-4ffa-11e5-bad3-52540011ed64'},
 'subsets': [{'addresses': [{'ip': '10.233.3.5',
                             'targetRef': {'kind': 'Pod',
                                           'name': 'monitoring-influx-grafana-v1-obu8h',
                                           'namespace': 'kube-system',
                                           'resourceVersion': '391',
                                           'uid': 'fa6fb734-4ffa-11e5-bad3-52540011ed64'}}],
              'ports': [{'name': 'http', 'port': 8083, 'protocol': 'TCP'},
                        {'name': 'api', 'port': 8086, 'protocol': 'TCP'}]}]}
```

i think this problem causes errors for other pods too

```
kubectl logs kibana-logging-v1-ifztn --namespace=kube-system
...
{"@timestamp":"2015-08-31T16:13:29.082Z","level":"info","message":"Unable to connect to elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch-logging:9200. Retrying in 2.5 seconds.","node_env":"production"}
...

kubectl logs monitoring-heapster-v8-9cy06 --namespace=kube-system
...
E0831 16:12:27.367871       1 driver.go:326] Database creation failed: Post http://monitoring-influxdb:8086/db?u=root&p=root: dial tcp: lookup monitoring-influxdb: no such host. Retrying after 30 seconds
...
```

Regards,
Smana

Comment: Actually i've done further tests and i'm not sure it is related to name resolution now. i'll keep you updated

Comment: I experienced something similar, that was the result of DNS for service discovery and routing not working between two containers in the same pod. Within the influxdb-frafana pod, you should be able to connect to the other pod at 127.0.0.1/localhost

Answer (score 2):

Smana,
1) Like you guessed again, it is not a DNS resolution problem
PING monitoring-influxdb.kube-system.svc.osm.local (10.233.83.114) 56(84) bytes of data.
the ping command indicates that is pinging IP 10.233.83.144

2) ICMP is not supported for cluster ips. Currently, only tcp and udp are supported. Hence ping fails.